# The most general linear map of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the most general linear map of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Obviously, dot product is one. However, I'm not sure how do I show that it's the most general of them? Or maybe, something else is even more general? Hint appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is meant by "general" in this context?

Comment: What does it mean for a map to be "general"? (PS: this isn't a hint. I'm asking because I have no clue what you are talking about.)

Comment: Can you find an obvious basis for the space of such linear maps (eg dot product with some special vectors), and prove that it is a basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with any two finite dimensional vector spaces, $V$, $W$, you can fix a basis for $V$ and a basis for $W$ and then the linear transformations from $V$ to $W$ become rectangular matrices which you perform matrix multiplication with.

So, one could say that a general linear transformation from $\Bbb R^n$ to $R$ can be identified with a matrix $[a_1,\dots a_n]$ where $T(x_1,\dots x_n):=[a_1,\dots a_n][x_1,\dots, x_n]^\top \in \Bbb R$.

You can see that this means all linear maps arise as the dot product of some fixed vector with other vectors.

Answer (score 3):

A linear map from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R$ is a function of the form
$$f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\alpha_1 x_1 + \dots + \alpha_n x_n$$

If you introduce the dot product $\langle x\mid y\rangle = x_1y_1 + \dots +x_n y_n$, you can see that $f(x)=\langle x\mid \alpha\rangle$.

In fact, linear functions from a $\Bbb K$-vector space $E$ to $\Bbb K$ in bijection with the vectors of $E$ with $\varphi(v)=(x\mapsto \langle x\mid v\rangle)$.

---

Since you say "the dot product is one", you might be talking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form

Answer (score 2):

A linear map is completely determined by its values on the basis elements of the domain, i.e.

$f(a_1\hat e_1 +...+a_n\hat e_n)=a_1f(\hat e_1)+...+a_nf(\hat e_n)$.

This means if the $a_i$ are elements of a column vector in $\mathbb R^n$, $f$ is the row vector consisting of $f(\hat e_i)$ as its entries.

Answer (score 1):

Any linear map  $\varphi:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is determined by the real numbers

$$a_i:=\varphi(e_i), $$

denoting by $\{e_i\}$ any basis of $\mathbb R^n$. Changing basis of $\mathbb R^n$ we get different sets $\{{a'}_i\}$ of  real numbers, but the transformation rule  is known.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: What is the dot product?

Comment: Can you say some more about where you are headed with this thought? It's pretty nebulous...